# Is there a way to verify that the current window of another program is totally visible?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

Is there any function, or I'll have to iterate through all windows that are in front of mine and detect if they overlap my window?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could investigate an API something like GetUpdateRect so that you can see what is being requested to be painted.  Perhaps Invalidating first.  Just an idea, not sure if it will lead to anything.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try comparing the HWND returned by GetForegroundWindow() with the HWND of your application? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505%28VS.85%29.aspx)

To be more clear:

```
hwndForeground = GetForegroundWindow();
if (hwndForeground != myapp)
  //Compare if rect of (hwndForeground) is overlapping rect of (myapp)
```

Comment: I am now looping through all the windows above mine to see if they intersect.